# Unable to add comments in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I was able to add comments in one of my excel files, by right clicking the target cell and then selecting add comment. However suddenly add comment option disappeared from the right click menu and also from the riboon's Review tab. So created a new blank excel file and tried the same. But as you can see in below screenshot, anything related to comments was simply disappeared from excel (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016):

[image]

Compare this with the excel from other laptop (Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus):

[image]

Why this is so?

Comment: Is the affected system subject to any group policies?

Comment: Have you tried quitting and restarting Excel?

Comment: If you have multiple sheets selected (grouped), the Comment option is disabled. But that doesn't appear to be the case from your screenshot. You can try issuing `CommandBars("Cell").Reset` in an immediate window in the code editor.

Comment: Did you check if you can add this option back to Ribbon from File- Options- Customize Ribbon?

Comment: Yeah sorry for late reply. The issue is resolved. I dont know how. I usually hibernate my PC and also keep my files open for several days. But if I remember it right, my PC was restarted some days back (more sort of sense it right, because I have considerably less number of files open. Usually I end up many open files and 30+ chrome tab). And it happened that I opened the same file again and now I am able to add comment. Am afraid the issue shouldnt come back, as I was not at all able to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Got this issue too, tried to solve it, but instead found an alternative way to insert a comment:

1. Select the cell you want to insert the comment.
2. Go on 'Tell me what you want to do' next to 'Help'.
3. Type 'Insert Comment', and press enter.

It worked fine for me.